# Crispr-Cas9 method and nobel

Tags: genetics

Since i had my first cell class at university i have heard about Cripsr Cas9 method. But I am quite surprised about one fact.  Why actually wasnt rewarded by Nobel price? Is it something like Einsteins relativity (to early to reward it)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology in the terms of SE Biology.

Comment: This question might be on topic on [Academia.SE](academia.stackexchange.com) but not on Biology.SE.

Comment: i am so sorry but i thought there will be some kind of biological problem with this  method and not only rivarly with money thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that some people (likely Jennifer Doudna, Emmanuelle Charpentier and Feng Zhang) will eventually be awarded a Nobel Prize for the discovery of CRISPR and the development of its applications for genome editing, because it really is a major advance. But for now, [the University of California Berkeley and the Broad Institute are still legally fighting over patent conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR#Patents_and_commercialization), and the patent situation worldwide is generally complicated. I think this is a possible reason why the Nobel committee decided to wait.